# How to add pull and push functionality to a column offset in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, multiple-columns

I am creating a section that has an image in one column and text on the other. I used pull/push on the columns so that it would flip them when the screen is large. However I've added a col-offset to one of the columns and I don't know how to flip it as well.

How do I do this?

Thanks

**Code**

```
<div class="smartphone">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="smartphone-container col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-push-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
            <div id="smartphone-screenshot" class="screenshot">
                <img src="img/como-funciona/smartphone1.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4 col-md-pull-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
            <h2>Some header</h2>
            <h1>Other Header</h1>
            <ul>
                <li> Item 1.</li>
                <li> Item 2</li>
                <li> Item 3</li>
            </ul>    
        </div> <!-- column -->
    </div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- end smartphone -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demonstration. Since offsets are pushing the position, you actually don't need them if you're pulling and pushing, you can just use the push to push it out more. In any case, it needs to add up to 12.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/hequt/1/edit

[image]

```
  <div class="container">
  
    BEFORE
    
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        Column first in content
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2">
        Column second in content
      </div>

      </div><!--/.row-->    
    
  </div><!--/.container-->
  
  <hr>
  
 
  
  <div class="container">
  
    AFTER 
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-push-7">
        Column first in content
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-pull-5">
        Column second in content
      </div>

      </div><!--/.row-->    
    
  </div><!--/.container-->
```